# Best place to store an array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and my app has the need for select boxes with half-hourly times in various different views throughout.

Here's an example of how the array data looks:

```
[
    '00:00' => '00:00',
    '00:30' => '00:30',
    '01:00' => '01:00',

    /* ... etc ... */

    '18:00' => '18:00',
    '18:30' => '18:30',
    '19:00' => '19:00',

    /* ... etc ... */
]
```

Obviously I don't want to put this in each controller that calls each view, but I'm wondering what the best way of storing it would be. So far, I've thought of the following:

1) A helper function that returns the array

2) A config file in app/config that contains the array

3) A database model (seems excessive)

4) A function that generates the list each time (performance concern?)

Can anyone think of a better way or suggest which one of the ways above would be best and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very good solution to this on Laracasts at https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/5

Here are the steps:

1) Create a file app/Http/Utilities.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Utilities;

class Time
{
    protected static $times = [
        '00:00' => '00:00', '00:30' => '00:30', '01:00' => '01:00'
        /** etc ... **/
        '22:30' => '22:30', '23:00' => '23:00', '23:30' => '23:30'
    ];

    public static function all()
    {
        return static::$times;
}
```

2) In the view, add the following at the top:

```
@inject ('times','App\Http\Utilities\Time')
```

3) `$times::all()` can now be used within the view wherever necessary.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I like that this is vanilla PHP, always good to know how to do stuff without framework magic!

Comment: Another thought : one could store  some useful arrays in the same way on the relevant model class, and write a get method for each one? Since one is bring in that model for the relevant views anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form Macro with Laravel Collective Package

Laravel Collective: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html

An awesome example you can find https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate

See **App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider.php**

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, this would be a perfect situation for [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers), as it seems like you have some data that has to be generated on multiple views and/or in multiple controller methods.

The way I go about doing this:

- Start by running `php artisan make:provider ComposerProvider` in your terminal.
- This is what that provider could look like:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

  class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
      /**
       * Bootstrap the application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {
          view()->composer(
              [
                  'view_one'
                  'view_two'
              ], 'App\Http\ViewComposers\DashboardComposer'
          );
      }

      /**
       * Register the application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
          //
      }
  }
  ```
- There you can list all the views that need this data.

An example of how a View Composer could look like. I place these in the folder `app/Http/ViewComposers`, as the namespace suggests.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Users\Repository as UserRepository;

class DashboardComposer
{


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $the_variable = 'Hello World';
        $data = [
            'some_very_important_variable' => $the_variable
        ];

        $view->with($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think that is overkill in this case as I only want to populate a dropdown menu. However, I can see how this approach would be useful for more complexed situations.